# Selenium Script (Java) Stops after few link clicks execution

Tags: java, selenium

I have a selenium script written in java which traverses the links by clicking them and then navigating back to the source page where the link was clicked, and the process continues with other links in the list.
The problem that I am facing is, after certain amount of time the process stops without throwing any error. The script just hangs or halts!

Comment: probably a timing issue. Put more delays and inspect the execution step by step.

Comment: Can you share your code here ? None can explain what really happens without a proper question or evidence.

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? Please read the help topics on how to ask a good question. You need to research your own issue, find code samples, etc. and write your own code to solve the issue. If you do all that and still can't figure it out, then come back and edit your question and add notes from the research you did, the code you have tried, and what the result was... any error messages, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of time issue. When we clicked on any link or button on a page for eg. `driver.findElement(By.xpath("###")).click();`
after clicking on that link or button,
wait until that page is loaded completely on the browser 
then give implicit wait command

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

then navigate back or forward

```
driver.navigate().back();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
or 
driver.navigate().forward();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: Thanks it seemed to solve the problem. Thank you everyone too.